# I want to show filtered list in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

Following is my code:

```
retrieveListItems('https://sustec29-public.sharepoint.com');

function retrieveListItems(siteUrl) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml(
    '<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
    '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query>' + 
    '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>'
);
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
); 
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
        '\ngroup: ' + oListItem.get_item('group') + 
        '\ndisc: ' + oListItem.get_item('disc');
}    
        $('#message').text(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

But browser gives error: " The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested."

If I write

```
        '\ntitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('title') + 
        '\nbody: ' + oListItem.get_item('body');
```

and rename field table's -  all ok.

But I want add my own field.

Answer (score 0):

The message:

> The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been
>   requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be
>   explicitly requested

stands for that not all list item properties have been retrieved.

[SP.ClientContext.load method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168903.aspx) is overloaded and the method also accepts  a second parameter for specifying the properties that have to be loaded.
In your example, please try to specify fields explicitly:

```
clientContext.load(collListItem,"ID,Title,Body,group,disc");
```